# Good simple VPS to S3 Backup scripts?

Tags: backup, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

anyone has a nice, simple script for backing up a VPS to a S3 bucket? can be ruby, python, whatever...

should be easy to configure!

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I use [Tim Kay's aws script](http://timkay.com/aws/) to do backups to S3.

Works well for my needs, which is just website files and mysql databases.

Not really sure exactly what you mean by "backing up a VPS" though.

Answer (score 1):

[Duplicity](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/) supports Amazon S3 storage among many others (local file storage, scp/ssh, ftp, rsync, HSI, WebDAV, Tahoe-LAFS)

Answer (score 0):

I have setup the S3 Bucket as a mounted network drive in the VPS (Centos 5), then configured incremental backups in WHM (Web Host Manager) and used this mounted drive as destination.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [AWS Command Line Interface](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/). The setup is easy. There are plenty of documentation and examples online. And best of all it is a native tool [openly](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli) developed by the AWS Team.

For example, you can sync a local folder (in your VPS) with a S3 Bucket like this:

```
$ aws s3 sync /local/path/ s3://my-bucket/MyFolder --recursive --exclude '*.log'
```

The *--recursive* option will transvers all your folders copying everything except log files (using the *--exclude* option). This is just an example. The AWS CLI tool provides various options (cp, ls, mb, mv, rb, rm, sync, website) to configure any kind of solution for backup.

Comment: From the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html) "Syncs directories and S3 prefixes. Recursively copies new and updated files from the source directory to the destination. Only creates folders in the destination if they contain one or more files." Looks like no `--recursive` option exists or is required

Comment: Hi @HarryB the `--recursive` flag here is for the [s3 object](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html#single-local-file-and-s3-object-operations) and not for the sync option. Make sense?

Comment: Makes sense if the operation is a cp, mv or rm, but it's a sync no? "The following commands are single file/object operations if no --recursive flag is provided". No examples on that page use `sync` with `--recursive`.